# Earphone calls instead of next song

Tags: ear-phones

I've bought Plantronics GO bluetooth earbuds and when I double-click them (next song) it starts calling my last call.

Any thoughts what goes wrong here? plantronics replied that it are my phone settings. What did I miss?

Comment: The Plantronics rep sounds creative. I've never heard of or seen that "setting" (doesn't mean it doesn't exist). You could consider getting some cheap headphones with a mic and play/pause button that works with iPhones to see if it works correctly. Chances are it is the earbuds' problem - just my guess.

Comment: @bassplayer7 I was using Apple earphones before (in-ears) with remote on the cable. They work as expected.. I was thinking, maybe bluetooth has settings somewhere? - Thanks for your reaction :)

Comment: Nope, there really aren't any BT settings at all. I forgot about the Apple earphones - those are evidence enough of the way it should work. I have Bluetooth Iogear headphones and they work properly. I would go back to Plantronics and push for a resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plus and minus keys are for next and previous song. Double clicking the middle button will start calling the last person in the "recent calls" list.

Comment: So you were actually pressing the wrong button?

Comment: Assuming that every device works the same on an iPhone and Plantronics providing me wrong information - yes. But I won't remove this question as it might help others with the same problem.

Comment: as you say it will help others that are wondering the same thing. If this answer is something you consider a solution you can mark it as an answer. :)